# Should users give text input when they report inappropriate content on an app?

Tags: user-expectation, content, app

I have an app with a lot of user-generated content. I also rely on other user's to report if this content is suspicious, fraudulent or inappropriate.

Currently the user can click a report button and from there select from a list why they are reporting this user - for example "This comment is insulting".

My questing is should I allow the user to optionally go a level deeper and provide a text input field for them to give more context, or should I keep it simple and just have them select a "report category"?

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, if you are actually going to read the feedback

If you are prepared to read the feedback, it's always good to allow users to submit optional feedback.  A common layout for this is:

[image]

This requires users to select a category, but allows them to also write comments optionally.

Note that if you do this, you should actually try to read the comments, because if you don't then you are really just wasting your users' time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be best to provide with one step deeper. One of solution could be when the user is about to submit the category you could give two button report or report with context for example and when user click the report with context button you just popup a text box let the user fill it and now a simple submit button.

Comment: Why do you say it would be best to provide one step deeper?

Comment: Being a user I would not like to type and fill and select etc. so the one who wants to go one step deeper should be provided with the view only.. Keep it simple!

Comment: I doubt making users think which route to take keeps it simple. The additional step can also discourage people to give more context.